# How to use boolean variables in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

Are boolean variables supported by Paw? When I import an OpenAPI spec with boolean query parameters, Paw seems to ignore all of that and convert them to strings. Furthermore, if I set a variable to be boolean, it gives a warning that

```
Parameter '<parameter name>': " is not of type 'boolean'
```

`true`/`false` aren't valid booleans. Then, if I export the collection back to OpenAPI, it converts the field back to a boolean. Does Paw not support booleans?

Comment: I'm wondering the same. I've tried true, TRUE, YES, and 1... none seem to work.